# Ruby on Rails : Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError in UsersController#update

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, heroku, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-5

What am I doing wrong?

**Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError in UsersController#update**
No handler found for "S__28434447.jpg"

```
 @user = User.find(params[:id])

   if @user.update(user_params)
      flash[:notice] = "edit success"
      redirect_to("/users/#{@user.id}")
    end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
         before_action :authenticate_user

          def edit
            @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
          end

          def update
            @user = User.find(params[:id])

            if @user.update(user_params)
              flash[:notice] = "edit success"
              redirect_to("/users/#{@user.id}")
            end
          end

         private

         def user_params
           params.require(:user).permit(:avatar, :name, :email, :phone_number, :description)
         end

end
```

**Parameters:**

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"hRL4l1uZtBP8N9uQZeImLSOyn/u10Qc7zXiJBkFvVJvzO7bS6DxGVpIozEu0fjWRAZU1YGsfMgj6bwNT1P1FFg==",
 "user"=>{"name"=>"admin", "avatar"=>"S__28434447.jpg", "email"=>"admin@gmail.com", "phone_number"=>"", "description"=>""},
 "id"=>"1"}
```

**edit.html.erb**

```
     <%= form_tag("/users/#{@user.id}/update", html:{multipart: true}) do %>
            <div class="form-group">
              <p>*ユーザー名</p>
              <input name="user[name]" value="<%= @user.name %>" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <p>プロフィール画像</p>
              <input name=user[avatar] type="file" value="<%= @user.avatar %>" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <p>*メールアドレス</p>
              <input name=user[email] value="<%= @user.email %>" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <p>電話番号</p>
              <input name=user[phone_number] value="<%= @user.phone_number %>" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <p>自己紹介</p>
              <input name=user[description] value="<%= @user.description %>" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="actions">
              <input type="submit" value="保存" class="btn btn-primary">
            </div>
       <% end %>
```

I use gem file
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2.3'

I use rails 5

I do not know where wrong.
So please tell me about the improvement points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this

1. Remove this line `<input name=user[avatar] type="file" value="<%= @user.avatar %>">`
2. And Add this line `<%= file_field_tag :avatar %>` in place of prev code.

Reference: [document](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/file_field_tag)

Happy Coding
Cheers!

Comment: It was the result you were saying. Thank you!